# skip a specific set of characters scanf is not defined?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, scanf

I was reading the documentation of scanf function in this page http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf and I thought I understood it well until I try this

```
 int main(){
        char p[100],t[100];
        scanf("%s : %s", p, t);
        printf("%s %s", p, t);
    }
```

for my input I used **test : scanf** for me, the result should be **test :** but I get **test scanf** where the scanf function skip the **:** I don't understand why, I think that nowhere explain, can someone explain me?

thanks

Comment: The `"%s"` format read *whitespace* delimited strings, and you also tell `scanf` to read and discard the colon. Any non-format character in the format string will be matched (and discarded) verbatim.

Comment: scanf expects the %s tokens to be whitespace delimited (tab, space, newline). Do you want to use  :(colon) as the delimiter ?

Answer (score 1):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/), 
scanf reads data from stdin and stores them according to the *parameter format* which can only contain a white space character,a non-white space character and format specifier.

> - **Whitespace character:** the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace
>     character (whitespace characters include tab, space and newline).
> - ***Non-whitespace character, except format specifier (%):*** Any **character** that is not either a whitespace character (blank, newline or tab) or part of a format specifier (which begin with a %
>     character) **causes the function to read the next character from the
>     stream.**
> - **Format specifiers:** A sequence formed by an initial percentage sign (%) indicates a format specifier, which is used to specify the
>     type and format of the data to be retrieved from the stream and stored
>     into the locations pointed by the additional arguments.

So when you claim,

> for my input I used **test : scanf** for me, the result should be
>   **test :** but I get **test scanf** where the scanf function skip the :

you are interpreting it wrong. scanf should skip the :(colon) or any character that you mention as its parameter. So when you provide an input like `test CharachtersToSkip me` with following code,

```
      int main()
      {
        char p[100],t[100];
        scanf("%s CharachtersToSkip %s", p, t);
        printf("%s %s", p, t);
      }
```

scanf will skip the characters and output only `test me`

Hope its clear.

Answer (score 0):

if wants the out put "s=>test" only, then why you are print "t=>scanf"
just modify the code like that.

```
 int main()
  {
    char p[100],t[100];
    scanf("%s : %s", p, t);
    printf("%s", p);
  }
```

Comment: That code will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when `printf` tries to print the non-existing second string. And the question of the OP is why the second string isn't the colon `":"`.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page of `scanf()`

> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters;
>   The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field
>                 width, whichever occurs first.

In this case, first `%s` will get the input until the white space character is occur. So your input is `test : scanf`. It will get the test for first input. Then it will skip the leading spaces, you are mentioning the `:` in scanf, so it will skip the colon `:`. Then get the next string.

For more example , try this code

```
int main()                              
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d ",&a);
    printf("a:%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, `scanf()` don't end when you are giving the '\n' after the input.
It will wait for other than white space character occurs.